# cdk deploy Docker-based Lambda, Dockerfile based on private ECR repository

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, amazon-ecr

I want do deploy a Lambda function with CDK where the dockerfile doesn't use a normal AWS Lambda base image, but instead my own image that is in turn based on an AWS Lambda image. Specifically, I'm using the construct

```
aws_lambda.DockerImageFunction(
  ...,
  code=aws_lambda.DockerImageCode.from_image_asset(...)
)
```

My own image resides in a private repository in ECR.

Now I can do `docker login` first to authenticate and I can successfully `docker pull` the image in question, but when I try to do `cdk deploy`, it fails with

```
pulling from host <...>.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com failed with status code [manifests latest]: 403 Forbidden
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A CDK deploy essentially does two things:

- Generates a CloudFormation template based on the structure you've defined in your CDK code.
- Deploys the CloudFormation stack.

The error you're encountering suggests that the IAM credentials you're using to initiate the CloudFormation stack don't have the required permissions to access the ECR repository.

If the private ECR repo resides within the same account as the IAM user/role you're using to launch the stack, you can attach the necessary policy to this user/role.
However, if the repository is in a different account, you'll need to configure access [through a specific resource policy directly on the ECR repository](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/repository-policies.html).

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. The role I pass to `cdk deploy --role-arn ...` has `AdministratorAccess`. Additionally, the error message isn't of the typical form "User ... doesn't have the privilege ecr:GetAuthorizationToken" that would indicate an IAM issue. Or am I overlooking something? I would be happy if I could easily fix it in IAM

Comment: Is the ECR repo in the same account in where you're launching the deploy?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, yes it is.

Comment: Maybe I'm just approaching the problem the wrong way, as I haven't found any articles/docs online trying to do the same thing. I would also be happy about a pointer to a better way of doing this :)

Comment: Try to use "fromEcr" function instead of fromImageAsset: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda.DockerImageCode.html

Comment: Take a look here too, for the correct IAM permissions: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html

Comment: Their image isn't in ECR, it's built locally, so `fromEcr` wouldn't work.

Comment: Finally got it, this was a hard one. Problem was, cdk internally assumes different roles while deploying, and I was only aware of the initial role that i pass to `--role-arn` Turns out there's also a `...cdk...image-publishing-role`, and that one needs to be given the proper IAM privileges. Thank you for your help!